# Making a LaTeX version of a textual logotype

Tags: accents

I want to create a macro that typesets the text "julia" with two slanted dots above the "ia" at the end, so it looks like this:

```
   _       _ _(_)_     
  (_)     | (_) (_)    
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  
|__/
```

Since `\.a` gives me a dotted a, I thought maybe I could use `\.{i\.a}` to produce the third dot, but it didn't work - `jul\.{i\.a}` just outputs "juli".

Actually, I'm looking to recreate the logo at [julialang.org](http://julialang.org/).

Is there a way to get all the dots there?

Comment: I know the tag "fonts" isn't the best, but I had no idea what to tag this and it was suggested by the site. Please feel free to retag.

Comment: Your reference below to the julia language icon suggests that you'd be better off asking for an equilateral triangle of dots over the `ia` rather than a mark over the `a`. @barbarabeeton 's answer seems to come closest.

Comment: By the way, you might consider changing the title of this question to something along the lines of "Making a LaTeX version of a textual logo", since it has turned out that diacritics and umlauts are not really what this question is about.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

[image: A julia logo]

I tried to emulate the original julia logo from [julialang.org](http://julialang.org/). Some features:

- The positioning of the dots is relative to the x-height of the current font, which means that they should stay in the right position if the font size changes.
- The word "julia" is set in the `cmss` (Computer Modern sans serif) font, which means the logo won't change if you change your default sans serif font to Helvetica or something.
- The `\julia` command is declared as a 'robust' command, which means that it can safely be used inside section headings and so on. See the picture below:

[image: A julia logo, shown at various text sizes]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{mylightred}{RGB}{211,79,73}
\definecolor{mydarkred}{RGB}{199,44,38}
\definecolor{mylightgreen}{RGB}{78,153,67}
\definecolor{mydarkgreen}{RGB}{43,129,33}
\definecolor{mylightpurple}{RGB}{150,107,178}
\definecolor{mydarkpurple}{RGB}{126,78,160}
\definecolor{mylightblue}{RGB}{49,101,205}
\definecolor{mydarkblue}{RGB}{20,92,205}

\tikzset{
  juliadot/.style args={#1,#2}{shape=circle,line width=0.03ex,minimum width=0.4ex,fill=#1,draw=#2}
}

\newcommand\julialetter[1]{{\strut\fontfamily{cmss}\bfseries\selectfont{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand\julia{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0mm, every node/.style={inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm}]
\node[anchor=base]        (j) at (0,0) {\julialetter{\j}};
\node[anchor=base, right=0ex of j] (u) {\julialetter{u}};
\node[anchor=base, right=0ex of u] (l) {\julialetter{l}};
\node[anchor=base, right=0ex of l] (i) {\julialetter{\i}};
\node[anchor=base, right=0ex of i] (a) {\julialetter{a}};
\path let \p1 = (j) in node[juliadot={mylightblue,mydarkblue}] (bluedot) at (\x1+0.02ex,1.4ex) {};
\path let \p1 = (i) in node[juliadot={mylightred,mydarkred}] (reddot) at (\x1,1.4ex) {};
\path let \p1 = (reddot) in node[juliadot={mylightpurple,mydarkpurple}] (purpledot) at (\x1+0.5ex,\y1) {};
\path let \p1 = (reddot) in node[juliadot={mylightgreen,mydarkgreen}] (greendot) at (\x1+0.25ex,\y1+0.42ex) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{The \julia\ logo}

\parbox{8cm}{
\tiny Here is a {\julia} logo.
\small The {\julia} logo is made using TikZ.
\normalsize The dimensions in {\julia}'s logo are relative,
\large so {\julia} scales quite nicely,
\LARGE when {\julia} is big, and even
\Huge when {\julia} is huge.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks fantastic! Great! Is it possible to make it work also in section headers, titles etc? (Try adding `\section{\julia}` to your document for error output...)

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer to make `\julia` a robust command, so it should now work in section headings and titles.

Comment: Again, this is brilliant - thanks a lot! Do you mind if I put together a small LaTeX package with this code and publish on e.g. github and/or CTAN? I'll of course make sure that you get the credit for this code.

Comment: Not at all, glad to help `:)`.

Answer (score 12):

here is an absolute kludge.  the amounts of kern may need to be adjusted depending on the size used for setting it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\large
\thispagestyle{empty}
jul\.\i\raisebox{.4ex}{\kern-.1em\.{}\kern-.2em}\.a
\end{document}
```

[image: output from sample code]

(from the verbal description, it sounded like you were describing the "hungarian umlaut", but that's not what your graphic shows.  i've tried to match the graphic.)

here's another try, with three dots in a triangle, and an unadorned "julia" for comparison.  again, full code, and caveat that the amount of kerning really is size-dependent.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\huge
\thispagestyle{empty}
\scalebox{2}{julia}

\scalebox{2}{%
\leavevmode\rlap{julia}%
jul\.\i\raisebox{.4ex}{\kern-.15em\.{}\kern-.125em}\.{\kern-.27em}a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `jul\.\i\raisebox{.5ex}{\kern-.07em\.{}\kern-.2em}\.a` seems a tad better.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking to recreate the logo at http://julialang.org, so this is quite close. I've been experimenting with the kerning a little, trying to get the two rightmost dots to move a little left without bringing the a with them, but since I don't really understand what's going on, I'm not doing so well...

Comment: @Jubobs -- thanks for enlarging the image, but i fear that the kerning between the "i" and the "a" got a bit tighter than it was originally.  (that's the reason i included the *entire* code, which i usually don't do.  the kerning should ideally be the same as if there were no diacritics at all.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, I had good intentions. Feel free to revert to your original post.

Comment: The second version here is really good, but I'm concerned that the kerning makes it difficult to use this in text over a variety of documents. The idea is to create a logo that can be used with `\julia`, much like `\LaTeX`, so it really has to be re-usable.

Comment: @TomasLycken -- okay.  the best idea so far is to construct a "fixed" triangle of dots, and figure out how to position it reliably with the leftmost dot in place of the "normal" dot on the "i".  this intrigues me, so i'll work on it, but it will probably take a few days.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I'm glad I've been able to [nerd-snipe](http://xkcd.com/356/) you ;) I'm very grateful for all attempts at this - it is really beyond my LaTeX skills, but I would be very excited to have a working macro. Thanks a lot just for trying!

Answer (score 9):

Maybe simply:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\huge
Jul${\textrm{\i}}\dot{\ddot{}}$a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is quite good actually =)

Comment: `\i` gets a complaint about being invalid in math mode.  you can use `\textrm` instead to get rid of the complaint.

Comment: why not simply place the `\i` outside of the `$...$`?

Answer (score 4):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Jul\i\raisebox{.55em}
{\kern-.2em \tiny\ensuremath{\therefore}}\kern-.3em a
\end{document}
```

One more:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Julia, Juli\kern-.85em\raisebox{-.01em}{
\r{ }\kern-.6em\raisebox{.2em}{\r{ }}\kern-.6em\r{ }
}\kern-.9em \ae 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried a combination of `\makebox` and `\raisebox`:

```
juli\makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\.{}}}\.a
```

[image]

This is quite similar to barbara beeton's answer but uses a zero-width `\makebox` instead of `\kern`ing.

**EDIT:** However, having looked at the OP's [source](http://www.julialang.org/) I've decided it's a bit ugly; the dot above the *a* is too close far from dot between the *i* and the *a*. `\kern`ing seems to be a better solution, IMHO.

I also looked into using the `\therefore` command from `amssymb` but it was broadly unworkable  - the symbol has too much space in `normalsize` but the dots are weirdly small in `tiny` or `scriptsize`.